# MSTSC Not working, disconnects shortly after connecting

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, mstsc

I'm currently having a problem connecting remotely to a server.

It is a brand new build Windows 2008 R2, remote users are enabled.
I'm trying to connect from a Windows 7 machine.

Everytime I remotely connect to the server it will stay connected for a matter of seconds (maybe 3-5) and then disconnect and I get the standard old cannot connect and list of reasons it could be. Then I cannot connect again and get this prompt until I restart the server. As soon as it's finished restarting, it happens all over again.

The network and hardware configuration between the two machines is completely reliable.

Does anybody know what else I could try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See my [recent answer to a similar question](https://serverfault.com/a/452604/2869) for instructions on starting the Remote Desktop Services Manager and pointing it to the remote machine. It could be stuck sessions.

Failing that, physically visit the machine and check the event log.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the time on both client and server.
- Check for any NIC connection mismatch. E.g Duplex
- make sure there is no IP address conflicts.

Comment: 2/3 of those I have done, but the time? You mean to the very second? Why is that an issue? (Out of curiosity). Thanks for the reply.